# Best way to post to a .Net Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I created a Web API with .Net Core. 
I currently have the form from the `.cshtml` page posting through to a normal MVC controller and then using the HTTP Post method to post to the Web API endpoint.

Is it better to post directly from the form on the `.cshtml` to the WebApi endpoint?

I'm relatively new so not sure which is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imho the current approach is correct: you post some data to a controller inside your application and then do stuff with this data (in this case sending them back to a Web API).
Why is correct? Because you can do all sort of checks inside the controller before sending any data to the Web API (like data validation, transformations, composition etc...). Also, I'm not sure if you can post directly to a Web API using Blazor methods for posts. To do that I think you have to write the form using plain HTML and than detect the submit event using Javascript, where you finally post the form data to the Web API. But again, I think the current approach is good (if not optimal)

Answer (score 0):

it's not a bad solution by any means but if your API is publicly accessible (not just from your web project with the mvc controllers) I would suggest posting directly to the API.

Posting directly to the API reduces roundtrips. And also the validation and everything should be handled by the API.

Answer (score 0):

Use Web APIs when you want to deal with data or HTTP status codes only, i.e. not expecting HTML to be returned. Typical use cases from a web perspective are doing any asynchronous communication through Javascript (native JS, Vue, Angular, React, JQuery, etc....)

If you expect HTML to be returned, use MVC or whatever view framework you want to use. In this case it is perfectly fine to call other APIs from the MVC controller.